# Two USB cams to two rtsp-simple-servers simultaneously

Tags: ffmpeg, server, video-streaming, webcam, rtsp

Like in title, I have 2 USB cams and I need to create two RTSP streams. I'm using FFmpeg and rtsp-simple-server and it's working with one cam with this configuration (rtsp-simple-server.yml):

```
paths:
  cam:
    runOnInit: ffmpeg -f dshow -video_device_number 0 -i video="UVC Camera" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -b:v 600k -f rtsp rtsp://192.168.5.203:8554/cam
    runOnInitRestart: yes
```

but I can't figure it out with second cam. I tried to make second instance of rtsp-simple-server in separete console and it doesn't work. I set it up like this (and few other ways with different port etc.):

```
paths:
  cam:
    runOnInit: ffmpeg -f dshow -video_device_number 1 -i video="UVC Camera" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -b:v 600k -f rtsp rtsp://192.168.5.203:8555/cam2
    runOnInitRestart: yes
```

I get this error as result: **Only one use of each socket address (protocol / network address / port) is allowed.** and I still think there is better way to solve this with proper configuration.

I hoping for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was easy, it's working:

```
paths:
  cam1:
    runOnInit: ffmpeg -f dshow -video_device_number 0 -i video="UVC Camera" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -b:v 600k -f rtsp rtsp://192.168.5.203:8554/cam1
    runOnInitRestart: yes
  cam2:
    runOnInit: ffmpeg -f dshow -video_device_number 1 -i video="UVC Camera" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -tune zerolatency -b:v 600k -f rtsp rtsp://192.168.5.203:8554/cam2
    runOnInitRestart: yes
```

Now I wonder how to reduce latency with this setup, so if you have any suggestions feel free to reply here!